# Error executing functions from own R package

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I created my own package with the RStudio build tools and building/loading the package via the build tools works fine. My functions run as desired and the documentation works fine as well.

Writing the package as a source file works fine, too, as well as installing the package from source. Though, when I execute functions after installing the package from source I get an "R code execution error" as well as the error message

> Error in fetch(key) : cannot allocate memory block of size 2.7 Gb

The size of the memory block in the error message varies every time.

So the problem is that I can't run any functions after installing the package from source. I need to be able to share the package as a source file though.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of problem? Is it related to writing the package as a source file? I could not find anything so far.

Additional info: When I run the "check package" command, everything works fine except for one error checking the given examples. The examples should not be an issue though, right?

Comment: I believe your problem is related to [this issue](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/210929417-Error-in-fetch-key-from-autocomplete-due-to-memory-limits) discussed on RStudio's old support site, though there wasn't a clear or specific resolution in that discussion. If you quit RStudio and restart it, do you get the same error? That seemed to help people who suffered from this issue.

Comment: If I quit RStuio or restart the session and open the package project again I sitll can't execute my functions after installing the package.
Interestingly, if I start a new session and install the source file in that session everything runs smooth.
This is really a mysterious error, but thanks for helping me find a workaround!